# capture hidden event accordion bootstrap dont work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap for my web and I add in a section the accordion component. I want to capture the hidden event of my accordion but this doesn't work.

```
$('#myCollapse').on('hidden', function(){ ...code... })
```

According to the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) the hidden event is captured in this way, but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Put some of your HTML code. `#myCollapse` must be the collapsible, not the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Transitions's plugin installed ? The animated events (`hidden` and `shown`) need it, otherwise you can use the "static" events (`hide` and `show`) they don't wait to the transition to be over to be launch.